# What is the connection between the amount of research data used and the reward?

Tags: game-dev-story

Is there a connection  between the amount of research data used and the reward?

I understand that the likelihood of success increases with research data, but after hitting the max cap, is there a point to giving it still more data? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a relationship between the amount of research data used and the reward. In my experience, the reward seems to be linked to the skill level of the worker.

Comment: The best workers also don't need much research boost...A trained hacker will have an 80% chance for nothing more than the 20 points you have to use.

Comment: In fact, you can often reduce the amount of research to even lower than 20 for such employees and still see an 80% success rate.

Answer (score 0):

There is no more point in giving more data past the limit as you will just be wasting your research points. However, later on you will be able to hit 80% with just 6 research points if you would like to experiment.